# Keyup in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to write in one field and after that opened by the following.I want thet if i enter the text in one field and after that other field are opening but other field dus not open's. Please help me

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').keyup(function() {
            if($('#name' == '')){
                $('#version').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
            }
            else {
                $('#version').removeAttr( 'disabled', 'disabled');  
            }   

        });
    });




</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        Version: <input type="text" name="version" id="version"/>
        Build: <input type="text" name="build" id="build"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/></br>
        <input type="text">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

#### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CpSyE/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#version').prop( 'disabled', true); // <--page load you have to dissble

    $('#name').keyup(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '')){
            $('#version').prop( 'disabled', true);
        }else {
            $('#version').prop( 'disabled', false);  
        }   

    });
});
```

This one is wrong way of doing:

```
$('#name' == '')
```

this should be:

```
$('#name').val() == ''
```

or better to denote it with `$(this).val()` because we are in context of `$('#name')` elem function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to test the value of the `#name` field, for that you can use `$(this).val()`.

Your test will always fail since the two strings `'#name' == ''` are never equeal.

Also it is better to use [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to change runtime dom properties like `disabled`, `checked` etc

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name').keyup(function() {
        $('#version').prop( 'disabled', !!$(this).val());  
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mZhYY/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider the `val` of the `name` input in your conditional.  I also think binding the event handler to the `blur` event would be more appropriate.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#name').blur(function() {
        if($('#name').val() == ''){
            $('#version').attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
        }
        else {
            $('#version').removeAttr( 'disabled', 'disabled');  
        }   

    });
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/C9297/

Comment: @Roman See the updated answer which suggests moving to the blur event.

Answer (score 1):

You have miss to insert the *`val`* of your div to check if is empty or not Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#name').keyup(function() {
             $('#version').prop( 'disabled', false);  
        }
        else {
            $('#version').attr( 'disabled', true);
        }   

        });
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wCMBV/)